# Make Syncronous call to javascript promise

Tags: javascript

I am trying to insert a record in DB before my program completes and sends mail. But the issue is I think my function is running in async and before I get a success message for successful insert in DB my programs complete and te never throws an error. Below is what I have tried.

```
Client.insertUser(sendInfo)
  .then(
    function (Data) {
      if (Data == null || Data.User == null || Data.isPersonaUpdated == false) {
        $state.go('register.failed');
      }
    }
  )
  .catch(
    function () {
      $state.go('register.failed');
    }
  )
```

**Client.js**

```
_this.insertUser = function (sendInfo) {
  var deferred = $q.defer();
  $http({
    method: 'POST',
    url: Globals.userAuth ? 'InsertUser.go' : 'modules/guest/InsertUser.go',
    data: sendInfo,
    headers: {
      'Content-type': 'application/json'
    }
  }).then(function successCallback(response) {
    deferred.resolve(response.data);
  }, function errorCallback(response) {
    deferred.reject(response);
  });

  return deferred.promise;
};
```

`Async` and `await` is not working since we are using ES6. Any suggestion on how can I make my promise call syncronous will be helpful.

Send Activation mail is calling a differnet promise and is not a part of the same chain.

```
Client.sendAccountActivationMail(u).then(function(data) {
            var isSuccess = angular.fromJson(data);
            if (isSuccess) {
            }
         });
```

Comment: Which line is sending the completion email? Everything you want to occur after the user insertion _must_ be positioned inside the promise chain. Your first code snippet is more idiomatic than your second.

Comment: You can't make async call into a sync, you either use callbacks, or better still return a promise.

Comment: @BenAston my issue is that the send mail is not a part of the same promise chain

Comment: What sequence do you want? 1. Insert User 2. Send email 3. Continue with program. (And if user insertion fails, handle error, and continue with program without sending email)? You can link the promise chains by returning the email promise from inside a `.then` callback.

Comment: 1. Insert User -- continue with normal execution of program. 2 Insert User if Data is null. redirect to failed state and stop execution without sending mail

Comment: @BenAston Basically what I am doing is just adding the insert line of code in preexisting code. There are lot of promise calls which are part of same chain and working fine. Its just that I want to add another peice of code which is not part of same chain and it should stop the execution of program. If I get null in data response

Comment: See my answer below. Returning the email sending promise from inside the `.then` callback will black continuation along the promise chain until that (email) promise is fulfilled.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you return a non-promise value from inside a `.then` callback, then it will automatically be wrapped in a promise. This will even work for the default return value of `undefined`.

This means that you can use an if-statement to conditionally create the user.

```js
function logIn({ shouldCreateUser, username, emailAddress }) {
  console.log("In logIn...");
  return Promise.resolve()
    .then(() => {
      console.log("In first then...");
      if (shouldCreateUser) {
        return createUser(username); // !
      }
      // If control moves here, a promise is implicitly returned with a value of `undefined`
    })
    .then(() => {
      console.log("In second then...");
      return client.sendEmail(emailAddress); // send email to everyone
    })
    .then(() => {
      console.log("Continuing with application logic...");
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      console.error(err.message);
      //catch any unhandled promise exceptions
    });
}

function createUser(username) {
  console.log("In createUser...");
  return client
    .insertUser(username)
    .then((result) => {
      if (!result || !result.user || !result.isPersonaUpdated)
        throw new Error("User insertion failed");
      console.log("User created asynchronously ok...");
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      console.error("Error thrown in createUser...", err.message);
    });
}

const client = {
  insertUser() {
    return Promise.resolve().then(() => ({ user: {}, isPersonaUpdated: true }));
  },
  sendEmail() {
    console.log("Sending email...");
    return Promise.resolve().then(() =>
      console.log("Email sent asynchronously ok...")
    );
  }
};

// Try flipping the value of `shouldCreateUser`
logIn({ shouldCreateUser: true, 
        username: 'Fred Bloggs', 
        emailAddress: 'example@example.com' })
  .then(() => console.log("All done."));
```

Comment: Thanks but this is also not possible as `Client.insertUser` is inside a if block and is only executed for certain type of user. But send mail is for everyone. I am sorry I should have added that in my question